# How can I edit an array element property that is part of a NavigationLink label, inside a ForEach with a textview?

Tags: ios, foreach, swiftui, textfield, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm new to SwiftUI and trying have hit a stumbling block on this one.

Essentially I want to rename a collection which is an element of an array, which is an environment object.

Firstly my data model struct: Collection

```
struct Collection: Identifiable {
    
    var id: UUID
    var name: String = ""
    let createdDate: Int?
    
}
```

My viewmodel class: ViewModel

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var displayedCollectionsArray: [Collection] = [
        Collection(id: UUID(), name: "Travel gems", createdDate: 12345),
        Collection(id: UUID(), name: "Collection 2", createdDate: 12345),
        Collection(id: UUID(), name: "Collection 3", createdDate: 12345)
    ]
    
}
```

Then my parent view: ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var allPlaces: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(allPlaces.displayedCollectionsArray) { collection in
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: Text("Detail View here"),
                            label: {
                                CollectionCardView(collection: collection, isHidden: false, collecName: collection.name)
                            }
                        ) // End Argument list for Navigation Link
                    } // End vstack
                }  // end for each
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            } // end scrollview
        } // end NavigationView
    }
}
```

Then my label view: CollectionCardView

```
struct CollectionCardView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var allPlaces: ViewModel
    
    var collection: Collection
    @State var isHidden: Bool = false
    var testkey = "hello"
    @State var collecName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                
                ZStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    Text(collection.name)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .opacity(isHidden ? 0 : 1)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 40, alignment: .leading)
                    if collection.name != "Travel gems" {
                        TextField(testkey, text: $collecName)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 40, alignment: .leading)
                            .opacity(isHidden ? 1 : 0)
                    }
                    
                }
                if collection.name != "Travel gems" {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isHidden.toggle()
                        }
                }
                
            }
            .padding(.leading, 24)
            .padding(.trailing, 24)
            
        } // End VStack
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is that because the textfield is inside my label view, which has a destination view attached to it via a navigation link in the parent view, rather than going into edit it when I tap on it, it just navigates me to the destination view.

Perhaps expectedly, when I click back from the destination view, the cursor is in the textfield and I am able to edit its contents.

You can see that I am using a `ScrollView`, and when I test a `List` instead, it does work, but I prefer a scroll view because of the way it is formatting my content with dividers and padding. (in the production version of my code, there is a lot more going on with `LazyGrids` and `Image`s etc that don't play nice with `List`).

BONUS POINTS! How can I programmatically highlight the text in the textfield when it toggles?

Comment: So you're trying to present the `NavigationLink` when the CardView is tapped, except for when you press on the text field?

Comment: Correct! Thanks for responding! BUT, if the user taps the cardView before toggling the textfield it should go to the navigationlink as well... Note that there is an ontapgesture for an SFSymbol that hides the Text view and shows the TextField view, so when the user taps the text view it should go to the NavigationLink, but when they tap the TextField, it should obviously go into that, and not trigger the textfield.